# Show function does not have limit using sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, real-numbers

Consider the function g: $R$ $ \rightarrow $ $R$ defined by 
$$
g(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&4-.5x &&: x\,rational\\
&.5x &&: x\,irrational
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Pick a point $b$ at which $g$ does not have a limit, and show that it does not have a limit there. Use sequences.

Now I know that it only has a limit at point $a=4$, which I already proved using the definition of limit for functions. So I know I can really pick any other point to prove it does not have a limit there.

But my question is how can go about it using sequences. I found a theorem:

$2.1 \, THEOREM$
Let f : $D$ $\rightarrow$ $R$ with $x_o$ an accumulation point of D. Then f has a limit at Q iff for each sequence {$x_n$} converging to $x_o$ with $x_n$ $\in$ D and $x_n$ $\neq$ $x_o$ for all n, the sequence (f($x_n$)) converges.

But this theorem proves that a function has a limit, how can I use it to show that a function does not have a limit? Also, I am guessing because I have the freedom to choose almost any point to prove this that it must make it easy to some degree. Thank you.

Comment: The theorem also proves that a function does not have a limit, because of the word "iff".

Comment: Namely, pick two subsequences that converge to different values. Then, the sequence does not have a limit.

Comment: Let $x_n$ be a sequence of irrational numbers converging to 0. Let $y_n$ be the sequence $y_{2n}=1/n$ and y_{2n+1}=x_n$. Try showing the sequence $g(y_n)$ does not converge

Comment: Ah, thank you everyone. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

We can pick for example $b=0$.

Let $x_n = \frac1n$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = 0$.

Since $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(x_n)=4-\frac{x_n}{2}$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=4$

Let $y_n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}n$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = 0$.

Since $y_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, $f(y_n)=\frac{y_n}{2}$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(y_n) =0 \neq \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)$

$g$ does not have such limit at $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, the example is very helpful.